# Obtener información de usuario del request en API en PHP

Tags: php, api, login, data

Tengo una API desarrollada en PHP, quiero guardar información de los inicios de sesión fallidos, por ejemplo, desde que ubicación se intenta acceder, desde que navegador, etc.
Los parámetros que recibe mi función son los siguientes:

```
  public function Login($request, $response, $args)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: Hace falta informacion y codigo